# Defining relationship in a model and updating the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am new to ruby on rails. As a part of my learning I created a sample application. In the sample app i have 2 models : tweet, user

I defined the relationship in my model, which defines the following : A Tweet has a User , A User has many Tweets. Here is how my code looks like :

```
 class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :user_email, :user_name, :user_password
  has_many :tweet
 end

class Tweet < ActiveRecord::Base
 attr_accessible :post_title
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Now I want to get this updated in my database. I wanted to check if there is anyway this can be updated automatically e.g. running rake db:migrate or something else. Or if I have do it manually ?

Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Did you changed/created the migrations to get this working?

Comment: You would need to add a user_id in your tweet table which will store the user id to whom the tweet belongs

Answer (score 0):

First of all add a column user_id in your tweet table, which will store the user's id, This user_id will be the key to identify the tweets of an user. And then change the line

```
has_many :tweet
```

to

```
has_many :tweets
```

and it will work.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks I modified it. But the relationship is not yet defined on the table in the database. My question is do I need to manually define it ? or will it be automatically taken care of by rails . I can't find a way to get this done automatically

Comment: sorry for late reply. And to answer your question, Rails will take care of it automatically.